Is there a better way to combine two DataFrames from two SQL queries into a single DataFrame?
Currently I'm querying two separate tables in a SQL database - one from which I get "data" from my_table and the other from which I get "units" from a config table. The units correspond 1:1 with the values in the data, i.e., each column of data values has a corresponding unit.
Because the query_units returns a single column of info, I end up transposing the resulting DataFrame with T. Then I concat that transposed DataFrame with my main data to end up with my desired result, i.e. a row of "units" followed by the rest of the data rows (see the example at the bottom).
Ultimately I'm trying to determine if there's a more efficient way to handle this setup.
Running two separate queries and concatenating the results (albeit with some transposition) works, but I'm wondering if there's a way to, say, handle this with a single SQL query which I can use to get a single DataFrame.
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

# connect to database
conn = pyodbc.connect(('<connection info here>'))

# query to get all data from 'my_table' between these two timestamps
query_data = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2024/10/24 11:00:00' AND '2024/10/24 12:00:00'"
# query to get units from the 'config' table for the items in 'my_table'
query_units = "SELECT units FROM config WHERE t_name=my_table"

# get a DataFrame containing the requested data
df = pd.read_sql_query(query_data, conn, 'timestamp')
# and a DataFrame of the units for each data item, transposed because this returns a
# single column and I want it as a row (using the data column names as its index)
eu = pd.read_sql_query(query_units, conn, index=df.columns).T

# combine (concat) the units row and the rest of the data, joined along 'df.columns'
# (the name of each data value)
df = concat(objs=(eu, df))

This is an example result of the above (NB: this is correct)
       data1    data2    data3    ...    dataN
units  volts    amps     temp     ...    volts  (this is the row that gets inserted)
11:00  10       5        69       ...    9
11:30  11       5        70       ...    10
12:00  12       6        72       ...    9


import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

class DataRetriever:
    def __init__(self, connection_info):
        self.conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_info)

    def get_data_with_units(self, start_time, end_time):
        # We use one SQL query with JOIN to combine data and units of measurement. 
        query = f'''
            SELECT mt.*, cfg.units
            FROM my_table mt
            JOIN config cfg ON cfg.t_name = 'my_table'
            WHERE mt.timestamp BETWEEN '{start_time}' AND '{end_time}'
        '''

        # Execute the query and create a DataFrame.
        df = pd.read_sql_query(query, self.conn)

        # Move the line with units of measurement to the top, use the pd.concat method to combine.
        units = df.pop('units').to_frame().T
        units.columns = df.columns  # Rename indexes for correct merging.
        result_df = pd.concat([units, df], ignore_index=True)

        return result_df

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connection_info = "<connection info here>"
    retriever = DataRetriever(connection_info)
    start_time = '2024/10/24 11:00:00'
    end_time = '2024/10/24 12:00:00'
    data_with_units = retriever.get_data_with_units(start_time, end_time)
    print(data_with_units)



I think I get where you're going with this, but it produces duplicate data rows (likely a side effect of JOIN?). Unfortunately my SQL-fu is weak, so I'm trying to figure out a fix/workaround. If I can nail that down, this is perfect.
